# How can I delete an item from a list using CInt and Split in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, list, split, int

I want to delete an item from a list and from a database. This is the code I used:

```
Dim nr As Integer
        Dim s As String
        s = lstPatiënten.ToString
        nr = CInt(s.Split("-"c)(0))
        For Each d In patienten
            If d.nr = nr Then
                If patientenDB.PatientVerwijderen(d) > 0 Then
                    initGetPatienten()
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

But it don't work.. The error is:

> Conversion from string "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox, It" to type
>   'Integer' is not valid.

But when I type Nr = 83 (83 is my UserID for a patiënt) it worked.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `s = lstPatiënten.ToString` to `s = lstPatiënten.SelectedItem.ToString`. Give that a whirl and let me know if it works.

[Listbox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx)